# mongoengine filter on DictField's dynamic keys

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

```
class UserThings(DynamicDocument):
    username = StringField()
    things = DictField()

dcrosta_things = UserThings(username='dcrosta')
dcrosta_things.things['foo'] = 'bar'
dcrosta_things.things['bad'] = 'quack'
dcrosta_things.save()
```

Results in a MongoDB document like:

```
{ _id: ObjectId(...),
  _types: ["UserThings"],
  _cls: "UserThings",
  username: "dcrosta",
  things: {
    foo: "bar",
    baz: "quack"
  }
}
```

Im using mongoengine and I'm not able to query on dict field's keys.

for e.g I have a list of things  `thing_list = ['foo', 'faa', 'baz', 'xyz']`

and I want to filter all `UserThings` that contains anyof these things...

something like ..  `UserThings.objeect.filter(things__in=thing_list)`

definitely this wont work. IS there any way to perform filtering on variable/dynamic keys on dictfield. if not, can we do it using pymongo/raw query?